# Problem with Wildfly and Eclipse and library?

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly

I am creating a web app for a course, I have inserted the data from Eclipse into MySQL, but when I try to insert them via URL through a servlet, it returns error 404. I'm using Eclipse. I might have made a mistake in configuring the various libraries. Help meeee! I've tried everything, but the server doesn't work in any way. The server not work.  This is my code:

```
package ctr;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import jakarta.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import model.Impiegato;
import dao.ImpiegatoDaoImpl;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ImpiegatoSrv
 */
//@WebServlet("/ImpiegatoSrv")
public class ImpiegatoSrv extends jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ImpiegatoSrv() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
        System.out.println("Sono dentro");
        
        String operazione = request.getParameter("operazione");     
        ImpiegatoDaoImpl id = new ImpiegatoDaoImpl();

            
        if (operazione.equals("inserimento")) {


            String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
            String cognome = request.getParameter("cognome");
            String codiceFiscale = request.getParameter("codiceFiscale");
            int matricola = Integer.parseInt("matricola");
            //int quantita = Integer.parseInt(quant);

            Impiegato i = new Impiegato();
            i.setNome(nome);
            i.setCognome(cognome);
            i.setCodiceFiscale(codiceFiscale);
            i.setMatricola(matricola);

            try {
                id.inserisci(nome, cognome, codiceFiscale, matricola);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    
        if (operazione.equals("elimina")) {


            String nome = request.getParameter("nome");

            try {
                id.delete(nome);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
                }
        
        if (operazione.equals("aggiorna")) {


            String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
            String cognome = request.getParameter("cognome");
            String codiceFiscale = request.getParameter("codiceFiscale");
            int matricola = Integer.parseInt("matricola");
            //int quantita = Integer.parseInt(quant);

            Impiegato i = new Impiegato();
            i.setNome(nome);
            i.setCognome(cognome);
            i.setCodiceFiscale(codiceFiscale);
            i.setMatricola(matricola);

            try {
                id.update(nome, cognome, codiceFiscale, matricola);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
                
    /*  if (operazione.equals("findAll")) {

            List<Impiegato> listaImpiegati = iDao.getAll();

            request.getSession().setAttribute("elencoImpiegati", listaImpiegati)
            String nome = request.getParameter("nome");

            id.getByCode(nome);

            }else
            response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

    }*/
        
        

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }
```

this is answer of wildfly:

```
18:54:48,034 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 2.1.0.Final
18:54:48,852 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.5.0.Final
18:54:48,861 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final
18:54:49,079 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 28.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 20.0.1.Final) starting
18:54:50,746 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 2.1.0.Final
18:54:51,664 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 3) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'cluster' in the resource at address '/subsystem=ejb3/service=remote' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
18:54:51,747 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found Gestionale1.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called Gestionale1.war.dodeploy
18:54:51,929 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
18:54:51,954 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO version 3.8.9.Final
18:54:51,965 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.8.9.Final
18:54:52,046 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 6.2.3.Final
18:54:52,057 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.health] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYHEALTH0001: Activating Base Health Subsystem
18:54:52,058 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.elytron.oidc._private] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYOIDC0001: Activating WildFly Elytron OIDC Subsystem
18:54:52,061 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
18:54:52,081 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 2.1)
18:54:52,102 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
18:54:52,131 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.jwt.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYJWT0001: Activating MicroProfile JWT Subsystem
18:54:52,142 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.config.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYCONF0001: Activating MicroProfile Config Subsystem
18:54:52,159 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following Jakarta Server Faces Implementations: [main]
18:54:52,179 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.metrics] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYMETRICS0001: Activating Base Metrics Subsystem
18:54:52,193 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0009: Starting Jakarta Connectors Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 3.0.2.Final)
18:54:52,201 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
18:54:52,221 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
18:54:52,249 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "Gestionale1.war" (runtime-name: "Gestionale1.war")
18:54:52,300 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.3.5.Final starting
18:54:52,303 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
18:54:52,368 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
18:54:52,412 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.elytron] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYELY00023: KeyStore file 'C:\Users\Utente\wildfly-28.0.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore' does not exist. Used blank.
18:54:52,478 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.elytron] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYELY01084: KeyStore C:\Users\Utente\wildfly-28.0.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto-generated on first use with a self-signed certificate for host localhost
18:54:52,553 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\Users\Utente\wildfly-28.0.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
18:54:53,300 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
18:54:53,348 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 IO threads with 64 max task threads based on your 4 available processors
18:54:53,363 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
18:54:53,363 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
18:54:53,415 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
18:54:53,435 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\Utente\wildfly-28.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments
18:54:53,455 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.27.Final
18:54:53,510 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
18:54:53,514 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) Queuing requests.
18:54:53,520 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
18:54:53,582 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
18:54:53,584 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
18:54:53,650 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEJB0493: Jakarta Enterprise Beans subsystem suspension complete
18:54:53,777 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 6.2.0.Final (Apache CXF 4.0.0) 
18:54:53,793 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
18:54:54,576 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 79) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/Gestionale1' for server 'default-server'
18:54:54,673 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "Gestionale1.war" (runtime-name : "Gestionale1.war")
18:54:54,743 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
18:54:54,753 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
18:54:54,755 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
18:54:54,760 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 28.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 20.0.1.Final) started in 7452ms - Started 365 of 587 services (321 services are lazy, passive or on-demand) - Server configuration file in use: standalone.xml
18:54:55,177 INFO  [org.jboss.as.protocol] (management I/O-1) WFLYPRT0057:  cancelled task by interrupting thread Thread[management-handler-thread - 1,5,management-handler-thread]
18:54:55,189 INFO  [org.jboss.as.protocol] (management I/O-2) WFLYPRT0057:  cancelled task by interrupting thread Thread[management-handler-thread - 2,5,management-handler-thread]
18:54:55,246 INFO  [org.jboss.as.protocol] (management I/O-2) WFLYPRT0057:  cancelled task by interrupting thread Thread[management-handler-thread - 2,5,management-handler-thread]
```

Comment: Narrow it down and focus on the details. What exactly doesn't work that should? Pick one scenario and start from there. The only response to what you've supplied so far is likely to be to recreate the web app from scratch so that the libraries *aren't* mistakenly configured.

Comment: I have already recreated the application, but it still doesn't start. I don't understand the error messages that Wildfly is returning to me: org.jboss.as.protocol] (management I/O-1) WFLYPRT0057:  cancelled task by interrupting thread Thread[management-handler-thread - 1,5,management-handler-thread]

Comment: You have, again, not added included details about the 404 error. What the URL was. Why it *should* have worked. Log lines with actual ERROR severity.